# Why Java Set contains an object to add but no Set elements are equal to this object

Tags: java, collections, openjpa

First I get the list of objects class Product using an OpenJPA JPQL query.  Class Product corresponds to a database table mapped by OpenJPA.  It is from the Elastic Path software.

Then I am trying to create a Set from these objects.  The last object cannot be added, so contains indicates that this object is already in the set.  For understanding I iterate through the Set but no existent element is equal to the new object.

Moreover the hashCode is different for all objects.

That is the simplified code:

```
    List<Product> allProductsForPass = storeProductService.getProducts();
    Set<Product> sortProducts = new TreeSet<Product>(new ProductSort());

    for (Product iterProduct : allProductsForPass) {
        if (sortProducts.contains(iterProduct)) {
            for (Product sortProduct : sortProducts) {
                log.debug("SortProductHashCode" + sortProduct.hashCode()
                        + "; iterProductHashCode"
                        + iterProduct.hashCode());
                if (sortProduct.equals(iterProduct)) {
                    log.debug("SortProductFoundEqual:")
                }
            }
        }
        sortProducts.add(product);
    }
```

Comment: what about your `equals`?

Comment: Please post the code for **SdiProductSort**.

Comment: We need the code for **Product** as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeSet` doesn't use `hashCode` and `equals`. It uses the `Comparator`'s `compare` method to determine if two elements are the same. In your case the `Comparator` that determines if two `Product` elements are the same is an instance of `SdiProductSort`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog That's interesting, since I searched for the relevant code, and it eventualy calls [this method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator%28java.lang.Object%29), that uses `compare` and never calls equals.

Comment: Yeah, the javadoc sort of conflicts with itself. +1.